# i want to check if the string is number and if it is to replace it with spacebar

Tags: c++

```
    else
    isdigit(message[i]);{
    message[i]=' ';
    }
```

**basically this is code there is a for loop above and under it there is an if statement if the statement above is not true else will be executed and check if it is a number if it is then replace it with spacebar
*Message is string***

Comment: Please provide [mcve] of your code - a snippet that we can compile on our own machine and that reproduces the problem. Also, please describe in more detail what is wrong with your current code (it doesn't compile/ it compiles, but produces incorrect output).

Comment: *"there is an if statement"* The code shown doesn't contain the keyword `if`.

Answer (score 2):

Your else statement is a call to `isdigit` function, and you discard the result. The block statement that follows is outside of the if-else statement (whose if part isn't shown) and is thus executed regardless of that condition (which isn't shown).

> else will be executed and check if it is a number if it is then ...

In order to do something **if** some condition applies, you can use an *if statement*. You can have an if statement within an else statement.